# Newtonsoft.Json - Deserialize generic object into a wrapper class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'am trying to develop Asp.Net Web Api which response will be always

```
public class ApiResponse : IApiResponse, IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _statusCode;
    private readonly string _message;

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    protected Type ResponseDataType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public object Data { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dataType")]
    public string DataType => this.ResponseDataType.Name;

    [DataMember(Name = "additionalMessage")]
    public string AdditionalMessage => this._message;


    public ApiResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode responseStatus, Type dataType, object data = null, string additionalMessage = null)
    {
        this._request = request;
        this._statusCode = responseStatus;

        this.ResponseDataType = dataType;
        this.Data = data;
        this._message = additionalMessage;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = _request.CreateResponse(_statusCode, this);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

How can i deserialize this kind of response to obtain a cast of the `Data` property into a object of type `DataType`?

For example if the response is serialized into this Json

```
"dataType": "UserModel"
"data":
{
   "name" : "Bill",
   "surname" : "Lob"
}
```

How can i deserialize this response with Newtonsoft.Json to cast "`object data`" into "`UserModel data`"?
There is some way?

Comment: You may need to implement your own `JsonConverter` class https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution of this situation, it is very simple.
In the WebApiConfig.cs file of the api project, i have added this line of code

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All };
```

this will add an additional Json field called `$type` used by the deserializer to correctly cast the generic `object Data` to an `UserModel Data`